# How to solve Py2exe freezer "missing modules" and "error 87 ?"

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe

I'm a beginner trying to freeze py file into an executable by using py2exe.
This is my error :

```
running py2exe
3 missing Modules
------------------
? _posixshmem                         imported from multiprocessing.resource_tracker, multiprocessing.shared_memory
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? test.support                        imported from pySmartDL.pySmartDL
Building 'dist\file_lambda.exe'.
error: [WinError 87] incorrect settings.
```

My "setup.py" file looks like that :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
 
setup(console=['file_lambda.py'])
```

and my "file_lambda.py" very simple :

```
print("hello world !")
input("")
```

edit :

I installed pyinstaller, but when I try to use command "pyinstaller [file_name.py]", it say that pyinstaller is not recognize :

```
pyinstaller : The term 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
    included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
        At line:1 char:1
        + pyinstaller
        + ~~~~~~~~~~~
            + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

does someone have an idea ?
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For convert .py file to .exe file. Follow the below steps for the same.(this test in python 3.5.0 and 3.6)

Step 1:
Install the library pyinstaller.
Type below command in the command prompt. Open a cmd window in your Python folder

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Step 2:

The simplest way to use it is by entering on your command prompt

```
pyinstaller file_name.py
```

For more details on how to use it, take a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/)

Comment: thanks for your answer ; ) 
So I installed pyinstaller, but when I try to use it, it say that pyinstaller is not recognize.
I tried to use the solution of the link, but it still doesn't work.
Do you have an idea ?

Comment: you must first install pyinstaller in python  `https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/`  plaese explain more about problem

Comment: I edited the first message for more details about the problem